# Display where an error is in a message box

Tags: text, msgbox

I use this code to prevent entries of text that are not valid email addresses. The user has a UserForm with 22 textboxes for a user to input the addresses into a range of cells. How can I get the message box to show where the error was? Or, should I put this "check" in a different place, like in the "CommandButton1_Click()" sub?

This code is in the "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" sheet.

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
    If Target.Column = 13 And Target.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & Target.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        Target.ClearContents
        Target.Activate
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid email address."
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
    If Target.Column = 13 And Target.Value <> "" And Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & Target.Address & ",""*@*.*"")") <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Email address ''" & Target.Value & "'' in " & Target.Address & " is not a valid email address." & _
        vbNewLine & "Please enter a valid email address."
        Target.ClearContents
        Target.Activate
    End If
End If
```